# Whether convergence in L2 norm implies convergence a.e.?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory, integration, convergence-divergence

How to prove or disprove$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n-f\|=0\;\Rightarrow \;\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\; a.e.?$$ Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: This is false. But you can extract a subsequence which converges a.e. See the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you very much, @julien. I am not sure if I should delete the post.

Comment: I don't know about that, actually. Good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. For a counterexample, consider the functions $\chi_{[0,1]}$, $\chi_{[0,1/2]}$, $\chi_{[1/2,1]}$, $\chi_{[0,1/4]}$, $\chi_{[1/4,1/2]}$, $\chi_{[1/2,3/4]}$,  and so on.

However, you can always extract a subsequence which does converge a.e.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Potato.